# Correct Buffer Size

Tags: swift, metal

I'm trying to set up an instanced rendering system using Metal 2. Everything works fine but, there seems to be an issue still. I'm rendering ~1,000 instances and every instance requires some data, which is stored in a uniform. The uniform looks like this on the CPU side of things:

```
struct InstanceUniform {
    var position: float2
    var layer: Int
}
```

and I need one per instance. When I create the buffer for my instance uniforms, I do this:

```
buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<InstanceUniform>.stride * instanceCount, options: [])
```

which seems like it should allocate just enough memory for my instances. However, there is always a "spill over" of data from one draw call to my next. I have two draw calls: the first is for rendering the instances and the second is a normal call, no instancing. I have two buffers for my first draw and only one for my second. But, when I debug Metal, the second draw call shows it has a second buffer attachment that is the same size as the second buffer of the first call and it is filled with random memory values.

Also, I should mention that modifying the length specified for the instance uniform buffer to be something like the original value divided by 4 doesn't cause any issues so I'm guessing this problem is related to the size of the buffer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two buffers for my first draw and only one for my second.

Buffers are not specific to a draw call. They are set in the render command encoder. If you set buffers into the render command encoder's table, they remain there until you clear them or replace them with a different buffer. They'll still be assigned for any subsequent draw calls, even if the shaders active for the second draw call don't use them. (Of course, if you finish with one encoder and create a new one, then the new one will start with empty buffer tables.)

As to the size of your buffer, the `layer` property of your struct is of type `Int`, which is a 64-bit integer type. Metal does not handle 64-bit integer types. So, there's inevitably a mismatch between your buffer layout in your app code and your shaders. You should use `Int32` on the Swift side to correspond to `int` in Metal.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I’m going to mark this as the answer but I have another quick question. Does this have any impact on performance? I could imagine having many draw calls with huge buffers being a problem. Also, thanks for the tip about the mismatch between Int in Swift and Metal!

Comment: I don't think it would have much performance impact. The buffers are not copied for each draw. They are copied (if necessary) the first time they are needed. After that, they're already on the GPU.